# EPiServer-error, Dynamic Data Store 6.2.267.1 can only be used with database version 6204, current version is 6001

Tags: sql, episerver

I have upgraded a database from EPiServer 5 to 6 R2.
Current database-version is '6103' according to a script run in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. However when I try to access the website I get the following error ('current version is 6001'):
Previously a copy of the same database has run successfully with the same website (same web.config and the other files the same (the only difference is the database of the connectionstring).

```
Dynamic Data Store 6.2.267.1 can only be used with database version 6204, current version is 6001. Make sure both database and assemblies are upgraded correctly. 
    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Dynamic Data Store 6.2.267.1 can only be used with database version 6204, current version is 6001. Make sure both database and assemblies are upgraded correctly.

Source Error: 


[No relevant source lines]


Source File: c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\87acb86c\7104e381\App_global.asax.j09cuuvu.0.cs    Line: 0 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: Dynamic Data Store 6.2.267.1 can only be used with database version 6204, current version is 6001. Make sure both database and assemblies are upgraded correctly.]
   EPiServer.Data.Dynamic.Providers.DbDataStoreProvider.ValidateVersion() +427
   EPiServer.Data.Dynamic.Providers.DbDataStoreProvider.get_Connection() +36
   EPiServer.Data.Dynamic.Providers.DbDataStoreProvider.CreateCommand() +16
   EPiServer.Data.Dynamic.Providers.DbDataStoreProvider.ValidateVersion() +75
   EPiServer.Data.Dynamic.Providers.DbDataStoreProvider.Initialize(String name, NameValueCollection config) +564
   EPiServer.Data.Dynamic.Providers.DataStoreProvider.CreateInstance(ProviderSettings providerSettings) +198
   EPiServer.Data.Dynamic.Providers.DataStoreProvider.CreateInstance() +145
   EPiServer.Data.Dynamic.<>c__DisplayClass1.<InternalGet>b__0() +11
   EPiServer.Data.Cache.LocalCache`2.Add(TKey key, Boolean cacheNullValues, Boolean overwriteExistingValue, Func`1 action) +140
   EPiServer.Data.Cache.ReplicatedCache`1.Add(String key, Boolean cacheNullValues, Boolean overwriteExistingValue, Func`1 action, Boolean broadcast) +28
   EPiServer.Data.Dynamic.StoreDefinition.InternalGet(String storeName) +172
   EPiServer.Data.Dynamic.EPiServerDynamicDataStoreFactory.CreateStore(String storeName, Type type, StoreDefinitionParameters parameters) +110
   EPiServer.Data.Dynamic.EPiServerDynamicDataStoreFactory.CreateStore(Type type) +35
   EPiServer.Web.InitializationModule.InitializeDynamicDataStore() +169
   EPiServer.Web.InitializationModule.<Initialize>b__1a() +5
   EPiServer.Web.InitializeEngine.Initialize() +235
   EPiServer.Web.InitializationModule.Initialize(EPiServerSection config, Settings settings, ConnectionStringSettingsCollection connectionStringSettings) +2832
   EPiServer.Web.InitializationModule.<StaticInitialization>b__4() +34
   EPiServer.Web.InitializeEngine.Initialize() +235
   EPiServer.Web.InitializationModule.StaticInitialization() +1490
   EPiServer.Web.InitializationModule.Initialize(InitializationEngine context) +47
   EPiServer.Framework.Initialization.InitializationEngine.InitializeModules() +343
   EPiServer.Framework.Initialization.InitializationEngine.Initialize(HostType hostType) +83
   EPiServer.Framework.Initialization.InitializationModule.Initialize(HostType hostType) +163
   EPiServer.Framework.Initialization.InitializationModule.FrameworkInitialization(HostType hostType) +68
   EPiServer.Global..ctor() +54
   ASP.global_asax..ctor() in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\87acb86c\7104e381\App_global.asax.j09cuuvu.0.cs:0

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +1136
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +111
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture) +23
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[] args) +60
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetNormalApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +227
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +107
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +327
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have had a mix of hotfixed and non-hotfixed 6 R2 environments.

You need to run the SchemaUpdate.sql script for the database giving the error message you posted.

More info here:
http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Shahid-Nawaz/Dates/2012/1/General-Hotfix-CMS-6-R2/

Comment: Thanks, it is working now!
After running the script I ran the sql-files of the Framework-directory.
Before that I had been manually running the files of the CMS-directory